# When I click on next button page number ascending by unknown order.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating simple survey and as I said, when I select language, 
and clicking on "next", page number ascending by unknown order. 
I cant find where error is. Logic of ascending is pretty random.

Can some one help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Declare main variables
    var step = 0, runed = false;
    var db = [{
        question: "Question 1"
    },{
        question: "Question 2"
    },{
        question: "Question 3"
    },{
        question: "Question 4"
    },{
        question: "Question 5"
    },{
        question: "Question 6"
    },{
        question: "Question 7"
    }];
    var tot = db.length;
    var lang;

    function reStep() {
        $('.pg .tot').html(tot);
        $('.pg .cur').html(step);

        if(step == 0) {
            $('footer').hide();
        } else {
            $('footer').show();
        }

        run();
    };

    function next() {
        step++;
        reStep();
    };

    function run() {

        if(step == 0) {
            // First step handler
            runed = true;
            $('[step=' + step + '] a').click(function(){
                lang = $(this).attr('data');
                $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
                next();
            });
        } else if(step > db.length) {
            // Question handler
        } else {
            // Result handler
            console.log(step);

            $('.qstripe p').fadeOut();
            $('.qstripe h1').html(db[step - 1].question)

            $('#next').click(function() {
                next();
            });
        };

    };

    if(!runed) {
        reStep();
    }

});
```

```css
html, body {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
}
html {
 background: url('../img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.pull {
 float: left;
}
.pulr {
 float: right;
}
.clr {
 clear: both;
}
.green {
 background: #8cc73f;
}
.blue {
 background: #29aae1;
}
header {
 background: url("../img/logo.png") center center no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 width: 400px;
 height: 133px;
 margin: 25px auto 0;
}
.survey {
 margin: 25px auto 0;
}
.qstripe {
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 line-height: 70px;
}
.qstripe h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 background: #29aae1;
}
.qstripe p {
 padding-top: 20px;
 color: #2c2c2c;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 text-align: center;
}
.qstripe p span {
 display: block;
}

.ans {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 768px;
 text-align: center;
}
.ans .an {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 width: 225px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #29aae1;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}



footer {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
footer .btns {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 768px;
}
footer a {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 width: 225px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
footer a .back {
 margin-left: 30px;
}
footer .prog-b {
 margin: 40px auto 30px;
 max-width: 768px;
 position: relative;
 height: 10px;
}
footer .prog-b i {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 left: 30%;
 margin-top: -10px;
 border-radius: 50px;
}
footer .pg {
 text-align: center;
 color: #29aae1;
 font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>Key For Care</title>

 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="survey">
 <div class="qstripe">
  <h1>We want to improve!</h1>
  <p>
   SELECT LANGUAGE FIRST
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="ans">
  <div step="0">
   <a class="an" data="sv">SVENSKA</a>
   <a class="an" data="en">ENGLISH</a>
   <a class="an" data="so">SOOMAALI</a>
   <a class="an" data="ar">العربية</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <div class="btns">
   <a class="pull blue" id="prev">Back</a>
   <a class="pulr green" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div class="prog-b green">
   <i class="blue"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pg">
   <span class="cur"></span>/<span class="tot"></span>
  </div>
 </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are binding click event in your "run" function again and again til it reach to total count of db size.
So try to bind click only once so it will perform event only once at time.
You can try to remove click event first where you binding click event in "run" function with ".unbind()" event.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Declare main variables
    var step = 0, runed = false;
    var db = [{
        question: "Question 1"
    },{
        question: "Question 2"
    },{
        question: "Question 3"
    },{
        question: "Question 4"
    },{
        question: "Question 5"
    },{
        question: "Question 6"
    },{
        question: "Question 7"
    }];
    var tot = db.length;
    var lang;

    function reStep() {
        $('.pg .tot').html(tot);
        $('.pg .cur').html(step);

        if(step == 0) {
            $('footer').hide();
        } else {
            $('footer').show();
        }

        run();
    };

    function next() {
        step++;
        reStep();
    };

    function run() {

        if(step == 0) {
            // First step handler
            runed = true;
            $('[step=' + step + '] a').click(function(){
                lang = $(this).attr('data');
                $(this).parent().fadeOut(300);
                next();
            });
        } else if(step > db.length) {
            // Question handler
        } else {
            // Result handler
            console.log(step);

            $('.qstripe p').fadeOut();
            $('.qstripe h1').html(db[step - 1].question)


        };

    };

    if(!runed) {
        reStep();
    }

$('#next').click(function() {
            next();
        });

});
```

```css
html, body {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
}
html {
 background: url('../img/bg.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.pull {
 float: left;
}
.pulr {
 float: right;
}
.clr {
 clear: both;
}
.green {
 background: #8cc73f;
}
.blue {
 background: #29aae1;
}
header {
 background: url("../img/logo.png") center center no-repeat;
 background-size: 100% auto;
 width: 400px;
 height: 133px;
 margin: 25px auto 0;
}
.survey {
 margin: 25px auto 0;
}
.qstripe {
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 line-height: 70px;
}
.qstripe h1 {
 color: #FFFFFF;
 font-size: 2em;
 text-align: center;
 background: #29aae1;
}
.qstripe p {
 padding-top: 20px;
 color: #2c2c2c;
 font-size: 1.7em;
 line-height: 1.7em;
 text-align: center;
}
.qstripe p span {
 display: block;
}

.ans {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 768px;
 text-align: center;
}
.ans .an {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 10px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 width: 225px;
 line-height: 30px;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 text-align: center;
 border-radius: 8px;
 background: #29aae1;
 color: white;
 cursor: pointer;
}



footer {
 padding-bottom: 20px;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
}
footer .btns {
 margin: auto;
 max-width: 768px;
}
footer a {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 width: 225px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 8px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: auto;
 text-align: center;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 100;
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
footer a .back {
 margin-left: 30px;
}
footer .prog-b {
 margin: 40px auto 30px;
 max-width: 768px;
 position: relative;
 height: 10px;
}
footer .prog-b i {
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 left: 30%;
 margin-top: -10px;
 border-radius: 50px;
}
footer .pg {
 text-align: center;
 color: #29aae1;
 font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
 <title>Key For Care</title>

 <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
<div class="survey">
 <div class="qstripe">
  <h1>We want to improve!</h1>
  <p>
   SELECT LANGUAGE FIRST
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="ans">
  <div step="0">
   <a class="an" data="sv">SVENSKA</a>
   <a class="an" data="en">ENGLISH</a>
   <a class="an" data="so">SOOMAALI</a>
   <a class="an" data="ar">العربية</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <footer>
  <div class="btns">
   <a class="pull blue" id="prev">Back</a>
   <a class="pulr green" id="next">Next</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <div class="prog-b green">
   <i class="blue"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="pg">
   <span class="cur"></span>/<span class="tot"></span>
  </div>
 </footer>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```